# Android back button not working as intended after background

Tags: android

I have an activity A from which I start activity B.

If I press the back button it will go back to activity A, however if I press the home button or change to another app and come back to my app the back button closes the app instead, so I can no longer get back to activity A without restarting the app.

I use no flags when creating the intent.

Java:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, InCallActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

XML:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
<activity android:name=".InCallActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Post you code of AndroidManifest.xml and the code of Intent.

Comment: When you go out of the app, android might be clearing the activities out of focus to make some memory. Try to override the ' onBackPressed()' method in your activity B and add the required behaviour

Comment: @SagarGangawane Added code.

Comment: Remove the launchMode attribute and try.Check this [link of launchMode of Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: @SagarGangawane Well it works now, thanks. I thought I needed launchMode for some reason. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @SagarGangawane is right. To know more about it check https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: @Masterzagh Welcome always happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing the attribute `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your activities, and check if it works.

Follow these links for more information: [Activity Syntax](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and [Launch Mode](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)